# set jquery range slider values not working

Tags: jquery-ui

I use JQuery range slider. when I dynamically set values for the slider it give me error

> Error: cannot call methods on slider prior to initialization;
>   attempted to call method 'values'

**My code**

```
$( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0, startRange);
$( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1, endRange);
```

where `startrange` and `endRange` contain dynamic values.

Please Help.

Comment: Are you updating the values for an existing slider? Or is this the initial setting?

Answer (score 1):

If you're attempting to set the `values` option, you will want to do so like this:

`$( "#slider-range" ).slider( "option", "values", [ startRange, endRange ]);`

Just calling `$( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0, startRange);` calls the Method, and to do that you need to init the slider first:

```
$( "#slider-range" ).slider();
$( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0, startRange);
$( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1, endRange);
```